# Pre commit hook throwing error https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang

Tags: go, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

```
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
Don't commit to branch...................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Check Yaml...............................................................Passed
goimports................................................................Failed
- hook id: goimports
- exit code: 1
Executable `goimports` not found
```

When running Go pre hook commit I am getting the above error. I did try to install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports but it still gives me the error. Any suggestion how to resolve this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `goimports` needs to be installed and managed externally to `pre-commit` (escaping the normal supported pathway)

from [the readme](https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang#using-these-hooks)

> - `go-imports` - Runs `goimports`, requires golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports

so you'll need to make sure that tool is installed and globally available

Comment: HI, I did install it. Is there any path I need to add for it to be globally available

Comment: wherever `goimports` is has to be on your `PATH`